# post an image, with request parameters?

Tags: java, servlets, post, parameters

I am building a servlet that accepts an image in a POST request. with each post there should be an associated ID. My question is how to pass these two distinct data values in a post, where one is a short string, and another is a large chunk of binary data.

I could have both as post parameters,

```
id=123
content=...megabytes of binary data...
```

but I need the flexibility of handling the content as a stream, as it could be quite large. I could also follow the above pattern by parsing the input myself as binary data, which I'd like to avoid. I guess I'd need to parse it character by character looking for the keys. ugly.

Am I missing the correct pattern for handling this?

Comment: would adding id= parameter to the query string, then calling request.getQueryString() manually do the trick?

Comment: IS there any issue in passing `id` as part of post data? And then getting it by `request.getParameter("id")`?

Comment: Indeed. I don't understand the issue in this. Are you parsing the request body yourself or something? Rather delegate the tedious job to a 3rd party API like Apache Commons FileUpload. You can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824) an example.

Comment: @nishant yes, there's a problem. the post data is large and i can't load it into memory, i need to deal with it as a stream. as soon as you say getParameter(), the entire stream is read, and parsed into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard technique, used in browser to send form data containing both text and file inputs, is to use [multi-part form data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2).

[Apache commons FileUpdload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) could be used at server-side to parse the request, and give you access to the uploaded image as a stream.

Comment: thanks. that is the more general solution. for my purposes, i ended up adding the "id" parameter as path info, which worked like a charm.